# Cannot install Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop on Virtualbox

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, 64-bit

I'm unable to install Ubuntu 16.04 desktop (ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso) on my virtual box.

When I try installing Ubuntu 16.04 desktop on my virtualbox I'm greeted with this annoying message

***end kernal panic -not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exit code=0X00000007***

[image]

However I was able to install and run Ubuntu 16.04 **Server** (ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso) successfully without issue.

I have tried many things which includes enabling virtualization in host machine BIOS.

My Host machine is an x64 based, see detail about host machine below:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise
Version 6.3.9600 Build 9600
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name OMP-EMBAH
System Manufacturer Dell Inc.
System Model    Latitude E6420
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz, 2301 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Dell Inc. A24, 5/12/2017
```

Below is the screenshot of my VirtualBox

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to boot another computer with this media. Maybe some corrupted file within it.

Comment: @Redbob mean I should download a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop? Remember I'm trying to install on a virtualbox

Comment: If the server installation works fine, you can easily upgrade it to your favorite desktop. For example,  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt-get install xfce4`

Answer (score 0):

For no obvious reason Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.3 refused to run on my VirtualBox 
However I was able to install Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 on my VirtualBox

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso